# Hello, I am confused with days calculation, can someone clarify this for me?

Tags: prepositions, meaning, count

for example

If you had shower on Monday(2.1.2017 18:00), then you had no shower on Tuesday (3.1.2017 18:00) and then had shower again on Wednesday (4.1.2017 18:00)

And it is still 4.1.2017 on-going day meaning the day is not over yet.

Would you say you have not showered for two or one day?

Before you read this, tell me what you would say and after that read this:

In my country, we would say I have not showered for one day. Because I showered on Monday so no count, Wednesday showered too, so no count as well. Tuesday =no shower so count. You get my idea?

But in reality you have not showered for two days...

So what do you think? Can you explain to me  how can I figure out the last time the person has for example uploaded a video if he tells me he has not uploaded a video for 3 days already?

Let's say today is 5.1.2017 what day was last time he uploaded video?

Comment: You haven't showered _in two days_, so there's been one day where you didn't shower. Assuming it's not 18:00 yet, that is.

Comment: Since it’s Wednesday and I showered today, I would not be talking  about not having showered at all. As soon as i’ve showered the count starts over.

Comment: I’d say he didn’t upload a video today (1), yesterday (2), or the day before (3).  He must have uploaded one on 2.1.2017.

Comment: Yes but today, I was watching a video on YouTube and the person has uploaded a video today in which he was saying that he is sorry for not uploading video for two days. Which does not match your understanding of when he last uploaded a video. Or I am I the only one who is confused with this?

Comment: Keep in mind that there are no hard and fast rules about how one counts "days" in such circumstances.  There will be variations depending on the context (and the author).

Comment: Okay so for example. If the last time I made a payment to someone was on Monday and Today is Wednesday. Should I say I have not made any more payments for two or one day?

Comment: You should eliminate the potential ambiguity and say "I haven't made a payment since Monday." As an aside, I think you should also see if [ell.se] is a Stack Exchange that you might want to visit.

Comment: @FREESTYLERsk - when your poster was recording that video he hadn’t posted a video yet.

Answer (score 1):

In English, here's how it would go:

I didn't get a shower yesterday.  Or, I skipped a day, or I missed a day.

On Wednesday evening, right after your shower, you could say, "I feel better now.  My goodness, I hadn't had a shower for two days."  This is counting Tuesday as the first and Wednesday as the second.  We are allowed to count Wednesday because it was a whole day, going around stinky all morning and all afternoon.  (This wouldn't work at 1 pm, for example.)

Here's another example: suppose your goal is to practice piano every day.  You practiced on Monday, you missed Tuesday and Wednesday, and at bedtime on Wednesday you say, "I've got to do better tomorrow.  I haven't practiced for two days."