# Days from date count

Tags: grammar, time, dates

If someone says,

> You have four days from February 4th, 2022 to complete this job

what is the due date to complete the job? is it 7th February or 8th February?

Comment: If given the job in the morning, that day counts. If not, you still need four days: 5-6-7-8.

Comment: Is this really an English issue? I imagine that it also appears in many other languages. Perhaps it is more of an issue for https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: It allegedly varies between languages: see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting#Inclusive_counting). But I would say it still depends on context.

Comment: [This question](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/63375/convention-for-counting-days-on-the-third-day) discusses Biblical counting. You might argue it depends on culture, not language. But a question on [how to count how many days you didn't do something for](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/366325/hello-i-am-confused-with-days-calculation-can-someone-clarify-this-for-me) was closed as off-topic. So I don't know.